# Selenium/Appium + Java : What is the real difference between methods .isDisplayed() and .isEnabled()?

Tags: selenium, appium, mobile-automation

While writing a code many time any of them get failed. How actually those methods work? Please great if you can help to stop confusing between those two.

Q - What is the real difference between methods `isDisplayed()` and `isEnabled()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods `.isDisplayed()` and `.isEnabled()` have nothing in common.

Method `.isDisplayed()` :

An element is considered **displayed** when it is perceptually visible to the human eye.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness

Method `.isEnabled()` :

An element is considered **enabled** if it's **not a form control** (button, input, textarea, select or option) or when the user interactions and focus are not blocked with the `disabled` attribute/property.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#is-element-enabled

For the default implementation:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js